# Magento 1.9.3.0 Database scheme

Tags: magento1.9.3

I'm looking for a database scheme/diagram for Magento 1.9.3.0

We have just upgraded to 1.9.3.0 and i would like to add this to documentation but cannot find it. Who has this? Or any directions on where to find this is great too

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most updated I'm aware of is the one from Anna Voekl for Magento 1.9.2.2: http://anna.voelkl.at/magento-ce-1-9-2-2-database-diagram/

Comment: Yeah i have found this one aswell, was wondering if there is a 1.9.3.0 one